# Pappus' theorem to find CM of disk with a hole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

> Given a disk of uniform density and radius $R=10cm$, which has a hole cut out of the left side along the x axis which has radius $r=5cm$, find the coordinates of the center of mass.

**To answer this question**

So this problem comes from the feynman lectures after he has introduced pappus' theorem. I have been able to solve for the correct answer for this problem in two ways, a torque base way and by using pappus IF we consider the origin to be the left most point. I am, however, unable to make everything work if we look at the origin as being the center of the larger circle. Therefore to get credit for an answer I will ask that you use pappus' theorem from the center of the large circle or explain why it does not work in that case.

**my attempt**

If we consider the distance from the center of the large circle to the CM as $x$ and we rotate the disk around by $\pi$ radians, we have of course moved the CM a distance of $x\pi$, the area of the object being moved is just the area of the larger disk minus the area of the smaller disk or $\pi R^2 - \pi r^2 = \pi (10^2-5^2) = 75 \pi $. Finally the volume generate should be the volume of a sphere minus half the volume of a torus which has no hole or $\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3 - \frac{1}{2} 2 \pi^2 r^3$ so in total I get

$$(x\pi)(75 \pi ) = \frac{4}{3}\pi 10^3 - \pi^2 5^3 $$

this however does not result in the correct answer and I am unable to find out why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you rotate about axis $x_2$ it all works out nicely because you can rotate the areas bounded by curves $D$ and $E$ thorough $2\pi$ radians and create two closed volumes (solids of revolution) created by the rotation of those two curves.

[image]

You cannot do the same for a rotation of $2\pi$ about the $x_1$ axis as shown by your choosing to rotate by $\pi$ which completes the sphere for you but does not complete the torus.

For rotation about the $x_1$ axis the best you can do is to take each surface separately and rotate the areas bounded by surfaces $D$ and $E$ through $2\pi$ radians which gets you nowhere because you find that the centre of mass of the area bounded by curve $E$ is at $C$ and the centre of mass of the area bounded by curve $D$ is at $B$.

Comment: Okay so to use this I have to be able to get a closed volume, and cannot just consider half the volume of a closed torus? Thanks so much.